# How to alert the id of each div in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using `v-for` in order to display divs with data from an array with objects and I want to alert the id of each div when I click on the span. Currently when I click on it I just get an empty alert, how can I take the `item.id` and alert it?

Here is my attempt:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-for="item of array" :key="item.id" class="box">
      <span class="x-sign" @click="getDivId($event)">X</span>
      <h1>{{ item.content }}</h1>
      <p>{{ item.tags }}</p>
      <p>
        {{
          `${item.participant.age}, ${item.participant.name} from ${item.participant.nationality}`
        }}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import dbData from "../db.json";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data: function () {
    return {
      array: dbData.data,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getDivId(event) {
      let targetId = event.currentTarget.id;
      alert(targetId);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
  background-color: #f9fafb;
}

.box {
  border: solid 2px black;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.x-sign {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be the easiest to just write getDivId(item.id)?  That way you got the ID but don't have to mess around with the DOM. If you still want to do it your way, just use <span :id="item.id"...> - right now you aren't setting the ID anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do event.currentTarget.id. it's not the same as item.id. Two ways are

```
<div v-for="item of array" :key="item.id" class="box">
      <span class="x-sign" @click="getDivId(item.id)">X</span>
```

or

```
<div v-for="item of array" :key="item.id" class="box">
      <span :id="item.id" class="x-sign" @click="getDivId($event)">X</span>
```